# Post Data Not Working // Access data outside of closure // Swift Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
static func createPost(post: userPost, completion: @escaping (Error?, DatabaseReference?) -> ()) {
    // We can assume that a user is already signed in
    // initialize the post information
    post.setTimestamp()
    //post.setLocation()
    // Grab the current user's information for associating it with the post
    if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        post.setUID(uid: user.uid)
        let findUserName = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(user.uid)
        findUserName.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            let theUserName = dictionary?["username"] as? String ?? ""
            //print("test:", theUserName)
            post.setPostUserName(username: theUserName)
        })
    }
}
```

`post.setUID(uid: user.uid)` <-- function works and will post user id with post.
 `post.setPostUserName(username: theUserName)` <-- not posting username field retrieved from users.
`print(theUserName)` inside the closure does retrieve username

If I remove `post.setPostUserName(username: theUserName)` from observeSingleEvent, I tested it with `post.setPostUserName(username: "test")` and it works. If I write `post.setPostUserName(username: theUserName)` it does not recognize `theUserName`

Thank you for your time if you're able to help.

Comment: Were you expecting setPostUserName to be called before createPost returns? Also, why are you not calling your completion handler?

Comment: This was just a portion of the code I copied. Yes setPostUserName to be called before createPost returns.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well that's not possible. observeSingleEvent is an asynchronous method. createPost will return before observeSingleEvent completes.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: I can't tell what you are trying to do. I know what a userPost is or how you intend on using it.

Comment: That code actually works fine. How do you know `post.setPostUserName(username: theUserName)` is not working? There's really not enough code in the question to duplicate the issue.